# Internet via Wifi disconnects when I connect ethernet cable to connect a ethernet device?

Tags: wireless

Internet via Wifi disconnects when I connect Ethernet cable to connect to a Ethernet device. Wifi is configured for DHCP and connected with internet - works okay.
If I connect ethernet cable with a computer card, static IP configured to connect an ethernet device, then it stops internet access. I remove cable instantly start working again.
I am setting up this on Latitude D830. 
Any suggestion to fix this problem?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a default gateway set on the Ethernet interface?  If so you are probably routing all traffic to the interface when it is available.

If you are using the Ethernet interface for a single subnet, you can remove the default gateway and everything will work normally.

If you have multiple subnets beyond the Ethernet interface, you will have to add some static routes to your routing table.

Answer (score 1):

I think ethernet has priority set higher that wifi. This happens with me in my corporate LAN. If I use wifi and suddenly plugin the ethernet, I get 2 IPs, one each from ethernet and wifi, but the ethernet IP is used by Ubuntu.