# Problem with wifi connection when usb ethernet is connected

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, ethernet

I have a usb ethernet connection and a wifi connection. My problem is that sometimes when the usb ethernet is connected my wifi stops working and I can't use the internet anymore. How do I solve this problem? I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

I read the following posts but none of them solved my problem.

[ubuntu server 16.04 wifi connection to internert lost when assign static ip address to ethernet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070869/ubuntu-server-16-04-wifi-connection-to-internert-lost-when-assign-static-ip-addr)

[Cannot ping machine on ethernet while having two interfaces active (Ethernet and Wifi)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266540/cannot-ping-machine-on-ethernet-while-having-two-interfaces-active-ethernet-and)

[Make wifi preferable over wired connection in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452746/make-wifi-preferable-over-wired-connection-in-ubuntu-14-04)

[Internet via Wifi disconnects when I connect ethernet cable to connect a ethernet device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195669/internet-via-wifi-disconnects-when-i-connect-ethernet-cable-to-connect-a-etherne)

**UPDATE:
my laptop is ASUS K555L and usb ethernet connected to a Lichee pi zero board.**

Comment: Check your routing tables, before and after, with `ip route`. ReD

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help us in resolving your issue, and for any members who run into the same issue in the future, can you please edit your question to include your computer's make/model (particularly if it's a laptop)? Also, you mention a USB ethernet connection. Is this a dongle that you're using, and if so, what's the hardware make/model? As you might imagine, I'm trying to rule out any known hardware issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file at /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml and put the following statements inside it:

```
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet dhcp
metrics 1
```

And then the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```